# Hide resx file in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resx

I need hide resx files in Solution Explorer. Other files should be visible but I need only hide the resx files. Anyone knows any extensions for Visual Studio or trick to do that?

Comment: Do the resx files still need to be compiled?

Comment: Yes. They have to be compiled

Comment: Then I would create a separate project "MyProject.Resources", then you can just keep the project collapsed. Alternatively a folder in your project, "MyProject > Resources" then keep the folder collapsed.

Comment: https://s30.postimg.org/a3dlcc69t/files.png It looks like this. And for now I can't change it so I need to hide this somehow.

Comment: I think the only option here is two create a sub folder "Confirmations > Resources > *.resx", there's no way to remove the files from solution explorer and still have them compile. Well without a custom compilation script.

Comment: https://s24.postimg.org/d8v5x1hyd/img.png is solution for this but only in half way this option on image can filter files but I need expand this functionality to show me all projects and files without resx files. I thought someone wrote extension for this but no :(

Comment: The icon you have pictured only shows changes pending changes, for source control, or it can be changed to show only open files. You'd have to create your own extension for visual studio to get the functionality you want, honestly the easiest thing to do would be to move the folders.